# Is the power of a finitely generated associative algebra still finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebras

Let $A$ be an associative finitely-generated algebra. I want to show that any power of $A$ is finitely-generated as well.

> Definition of power:
>   $$A^k \stackrel{\text{def}}= \text{ { all finite sums $\sum_{i_1, \dots, _k} a_{i_1} \dots a_{i_k}$  : $a_{i1},\dots, a_{ik} \in A$ } }.$$
>   in other words: $A^k$ is set of all sums of the form $a_1, \dots, a_k$, where $a_j \in A$, for all $j \in [1; k]$

Comment: Finitely generated in what sense?

Comment: @MattSamuel, has a finite generating set 
(all elements are linear combinations of generators)

Comment: Linear combinations over which ring? This is not true if it's over the base ring.

Comment: @MattSamuel, over the base ring...
What definition of "finitely generated" works in that case?

Comment: Trivially, if $A$ is unital and it's linear combinations over $A$ then it is actually cyclic because $A^k=A$. Over the base ring, if $A$ is not finitely generated as a module, then it is usually the case that neither is $A^k$. There could be special cases where it is, for example if $A^k=0$.

Comment: @MattSamuel, let $<x_1, ..., x_n>$ be the generators of A. 
Elements of $A$ are all finite linear combination of words in alphabet $<x_1, ..., x_n>$ with coefficients in base ring (polynomials). What will change in that case?